# How do I tell VSCode to load my shared dlls upon debugging c++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I have made up a C++ project with CMake under Windows which uses MinGW. My project's structure is as follows:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── CMakeSettings.json
├── libs
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── CRCROMGen
│       ├── various .c / .h files
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── crc.c
│   └── crc.h
├── test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── crc_test.cpp
    └── main.cpp
```

In essence, the libs folder generates a static `.a` library, which I use as a dependency to compile my sources in the `src` folder into a dll:

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBUILD_CRC_DLL)

ADD_LIBRARY(crc SHARED "")

TARGET_SOURCES(
    crc
    PRIVATE 
        crc.c
    PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/crc.h
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(crc
    crcromgen
)

TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    crc
    PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
)

INSTALL(TARGETS crc DESTINATION "bin")
```

In the build process, the dll is produced in the `build/src/` folder.

Now, my tests are configured as follows:

```
FILE(GLOB SRCS *.cpp)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(testcrc ${SRCS})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testcrc
    crcromgen
    crc
    GTest::GTest
    GTest::Main
)

ADD_TEST(NAME testcrc COMMAND testcrc)

INSTALL(TARGETS testcrc DESTINATION "bin")
```

In particular, they make use of the `crc` DLL.

If I copy my DLL from the `build/src` folder into the `build/test` folder, then my tests run fine. If I don't do it, then my tests fail because they don't find the `libcrc.dll`.

I've tried many things:

1. set `additionalSOLibSearchPath` in the `launch.json` file
2. set a special `setupCommand` in the `launch.json` file, e.g. `"text": "set env PATH=${PATH}:${workspaceFolder}/build/src"`
3. set the `PATH` variable in the `launch.json` file

```json
"environment": [{
  "name": "PATH",
  "value": "${workspaceFolder}/build/src"
}],
```

Nothing works except manually copying that dll into the `build/test` folder.

Is there a way to do it without that manual copy? I'd like to have the visual studio code debugger looking for the dll at the `build/src` location and running the tests successfully.

### EDIT

You can find the example repo here: https://github.com/zadigus/cmake-cpp-gtest. In that repo, you will need to change two parameters to suit your local environment:

1. in `launch.json`, make sure to set the right path in `miDebuggerPath`
2. in `c_cpp_properties.json`, make sure to set the right `includePath` as well as `compilerPath`

Comment: How are you running the tests? Using `ctest` or manually invoking the test executable? Please show a [mre]

Comment: I've added a link to the code in my initial post. I am running the tests in two ways: 1. just run the test executable testcrc.exe 2. run with visual studio code's debugger. I am interested in the debugger. I want it to start up knowing where the libcrc.dll is.

Comment: fixing environment PATH variable helped me. Try to use backslashes

Comment: Don't forget, you must append/prepend to `PATH`, not override it! The correct way is:
`"environment": [{"name" : "PATH", "value" : "${workspaceFolder}/build/src;${env:PATH}"}]`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I had to finally do it was by creating a symbolic link to the shared DLL in the folder from where I run my executable.
You will need to open PowerShell as an Administrator and run it. For example, if there is a DLL called libcsvdb.dll in some folder called c:\git\csvdb that you have linked your executable (compiled in some other folder) with, to make your program find the DLL you need to run the following command;

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "libcsvdb.dll" -Target "c:\git\csvdb\libcsvdb.dll"
```

The only benefit this offers is that you don't need to go all the way to the System Environment to change the global path.